# How to determine if a SQL query is atomic

Tags: mysql, sql, atomic, mariadb, acid

Two related questions:

- Are my inserts atomic (see code below)?
- How do you determine whether an insert is atomic (i.e. where can I find the spec that gives me that guarantee.)

Are there other improvements I should make to the SQL? The data in question is a table with invoices, each bound to a client ID and with a client-specific order ID. That means that the invoice ID and the tuple (client ID, order ID) must be unique.

The first version I have is this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS invoice;

CREATE TABLE invoice (
    id int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT,
    client_id int(11) NOT NULL,
    order_id int(11) NOT NULL,
    INDEX(id, client_id, order_id)
);

DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER invoice_insert
BEFORE insert
ON invoice
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET @max_order_id = (SELECT IFNULL(MAX(order_id), 0) FROM invoice WHERE client_id = NEW.client_id);
    SET NEW.order_id = @max_order_id + 1;
END//

DELIMITER ;


-- example use
INSERT INTO invoice (client_id) VALUES (1), (1), (2), (1), (2), (2), (2);
INSERT INTO invoice (client_id) VALUES (1), (1), (2), (1), (2), (2), (2);
SELECT * from invoice;
```

The second version is this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS invoice, client;

CREATE TABLE invoice (
    id int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT,
    client_id int(11) NOT NULL,
    order_id int(11) NOT NULL,
    INDEX(id, client_id, order_id)
);

CREATE TABLE client (
    id int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT,
    max_order_id int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    INDEX(id)
);

DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER invoice_insert
BEFORE INSERT
ON invoice
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET @max_order_id = (SELECT max_order_id FROM client where id = NEW.client_id);
    SET NEW.order_id = @max_order_id + 1;
    UPDATE client SET max_order_id = NEW.order_id WHERE id = NEW.client_id;
END//

DELIMITER ;


-- example use
INSERT INTO client () VALUES (), (), ();
INSERT INTO invoice (client_id) VALUES (1), (1), (2), (1), (2), (2), (2);
INSERT INTO invoice (client_id) VALUES (1), (1), (2), (1), (2), (2), (2);
SELECT * from invoice;
SELECT * from client;
```

The advantage of the second version is that it maintains a separate order ID counter for each client, which allows me to delete entries without facing the danger of creating duplicate order IDs.

Comment: You have two different questions. The first is a two-tier question of which the [answer can be found in the MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/ansi-diff-transactions.html), the other is a code-review question for which I don't think SO is the right place.

Comment: Hihi, that's a bit like people with C++ questions at the ISO standard. I appreciate you wanting to help, but I'm afraid I'm far from the level of understanding where I can extract the required information from that link. Thank you still!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I would question what value you're getting from OrderId.  Since each OrderId is clearly intended to be uniquely assigned to one invoice, why not simply use the invoice's id?

Secondly, even though triggers operate within a transaction, neither method is safe.  For example, suppose one client has max OrderId=27, when two invoices come in "at the same time".  The auto-increment gives them ids 53 and 54 say, then kicks off the triggers.

53's transaction starts the trigger and runs the SELECT, so gets OrderId 27.  Before it advances to the next statement in the trigger, 54's transaction starts the trigger and so runs the same trigger - and so gets 27 as well.  Each transaction then completes their triggers, and so ends up with duplicate OrderIds.

One mitigation for that behaviour would be for the triggers to perform the update statement FIRST (so grabbing an exclusive lock) before issuing a select to read the updated value.  Still that's horrible.

Better would be (a) use the invoice's id as mentioned above - or if that's impossible for any reason then (b) have an auto-increment ing ORDER table.

Comment: The separation of invoices and orders is unfortunately not subject to change, which isn't obvious from this restricted example. I think I have found an answer though: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-locking-reads.html The last part with usage examples actually seems to address my question pretty well.